# Caucus Badge award multiple times for one election

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, election

As shown in the picture below, I received 3 badges (so far) for visiting the Stack Overflow election page.

[image]

Comment: Ooh ... vote fraud ...

Comment: I now have a fourth.... And a fifth

Comment: I have the same problem. 7 badges.

Comment: Thanks for the report - **we've temporarily stopped awarding badges while we investigate this**. (Report on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381126/repeated-caucus-badge-notifications)

Comment: My notifications now correctly display the "Caucus" badge receipt once.

Comment: Same here. Guessing it's fixed now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should be corrected now. The crux of the issue was a race condition that allowed *one user* to get qualifying user history entries for the badge twice: this then caused the badge awarding logic to try to give them two badges, which violated a constraint and stopped the entire badge award process... *After* the achievement notification had already been created.

And this kept happening, every time the badge award script ran: identify everyone with qualifying history entries, send 'em achievement notifications, try to award badges & fail... Rinse, repeat.

Nick cleaned up the duplicate UserHistory entries, the erroneous badge achievement notifications, and re-ran the badge awards - successfully. In the near future, we'll try & clean up this logic a bit to prevent future errors.

Comment: `[W]e'll try & cleanup this logic a bit to prevent future errors` - Preventing future errors is the goal of all programming, right? ;-) Thanks for getting on this quickly